# alternative to cron?

Tags: linux, timezone, cron

Does anyone know of a good alternative to cron?  I would like something that can be run with  different time zones.

Comment: http://www.onlinecronservices.com/ lists a bunch of services, most of them can handle time zones and DST

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may consider [Quartz](http://www.opensymphony.com/quartz/wikidocs/Features.html) (a java-based solution), that can take advantage of [`Date` build in the appropriate TimeZone](http://jira.opensymphony.com/browse/QUART%5A-540).

Answer (score 4):

For the future readers, consider Chronos, developed and open sourced by AirBnB. check it out at http://nerds.airbnb.com/introducing-chronos/

Answer (score 3):

Just for the sake of completeness, [cronie](https://fedorahosted.org/cronie/) supports the `CRON_TZ` variable.

Answer (score 1):

MacOS X has replaced `cron`, `at`, `xinet`, and `watchdog` with open source `launchd` ([Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Launchd)). Process properties are described in a XML file, which allows passing arguments. Switching timezones should trivial.